# Segmentation core dump, from a newbie

Tags: c

Hi I'm new to C programming and I have encountered with this
problem in this program that is
driving me crazy (segmentation core dump), I don't know if it
is my computer or the program I
need help please and I will appreciate very much your help
thanks.This is the program.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  // Learning Arrays
  // new filename Arrays
  // by Pedro Menocal Ayon
  // This program pairs three kids with their favorite superhero


  int main(){

  char Kid1[7];
   // Kid1 can hold an 11-character name
   // Kid2 will be 7 characters (Maddie plus null
   char Kid2[] = "Maddie";
   // Kid3 is also 7 characters, but specifically defined
   char Kid3[7] = "Andrew";
   // Hero1 will be 7 characters (adding null 0!)
   char Hero1 = "Batman";
   // Hero2 will have extra room just in case
   char Hero2[34] = "Spiderman";
   char Hero3[25];

   Kid1[0] = 'K'; // Kid1 is being defined character-by-character
   Kid1[1] = 'a';
   Kid1[2] = 't';
   Kid1[3] = 'i';
   Kid1[4] = 'e';
   Kid1[5] = '\0'; // Never forget the null 0 so C knows when the 
   string ends

   strcpy(Hero3, "The Incredible Hulk");

   printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
   printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid2, Hero2);
   printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid3, Hero3);





   return 0;

   }
```

Comment: Where are the `Hero` variables and `Kid2` and `Kid3` defined?

Comment: Should be `char Hero1[7] = "Batman";` intead of  `char Hero1 = "Batman";`

Comment: `char Hero1 = "Batman";` - this is invalid C. Please don't ignore the warnings your compiler gives you. D either `char *Hero1` (since you're not changing it) or if you might want to change it later: `char Hero1[7]`.

Comment: char Hero2[34] = "Spiderman";

Comment: well this is gotten straight from a C book

Comment: Either the book is wrong, or you copied it wrong. What's the book called?

Comment: Please compile your code with some essential compilation flags to catch simple errors. See your compiler's documentation, e.g. for `gcc`/`clang`, you might use the options like `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -O2 -g`. (In fact, you don't even need these flags in this case, since the error is caught with the default warnings..). Never ignore compiler warnings, that's why I recommend `-Werror`, especially for beginners.

Comment: C programming: Absolute Beginners' Guide by Greg Perry and Dean Miller.

Comment: Chapter 6 : Initiallizing Strings.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, and it's supposed to be `char *Hero1 = "Batman";` -- or you typed it in wrong.

Comment: Damien Thank you very much it should have been as you said char Hero1 = "Batman";

Comment: problem solved and as Costaparas suggested the book has an error. i Hate it when that happens cus I like the book and I'm learning a lot

Comment: So the problem was char Hero1[7] = "Batman"; the brackets were missing along with the elements .

Comment: Wow thank you all very much  guys I honestly didn't expect all of these answers so quickly, you all rock!.

Answer (score 1):

You have got several errors:

1. This declaration:

   ```
   char Hero1 = "Batman";
   ```

   is invalid, and this is where you get with a segfault. It's because the `Hero1` can only hold a single-byte character. Therefore, you cannot assign an entire character array to it.
2. In this line:

   ```
   printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
                                  ^^            ^^^^^
   ```

   The pointed `%s` require, the type of `char*` or `char[]`. Although, this can be solved once the first problem gets solved.

After this, you won't hit with a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rohan.

It also is strange that compiler didn't warned you about this posibility. GCC 9.3.0 does it by default.
But If you ever will stuck with core dumps you can always use gdb it will very helpful in your future :)